# selecting values from combobox should display html form with with loaded values from database in php

Tags: php, html, combobox

I have combobox that displays the list of values from database .I want when i select value from on combobox it should display hidden from with corresponding values in database without using submit function(onchange="this.form.submit();") of combobox

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="display:none"  id="d" > 



                        <select name="id" id="id" class="span2" style="width:150px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                            <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "valet";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_companies`  ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



                 ?>
                <option value="">-select company-</option>
                    <?php                   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;
                             }
                               ?>


                <?php foreach($age as $key=>$row) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' " . (($_REQUEST['id'] == $row['id']) ? "selected": "") . ">" . $row["id"] . "</option>";

                    ?>
                <?php } 
                   }
 else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    header('Location: webservices.php');
}

mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>


            <form action=""  method="post"  >

                    <br><br>
                <br>

<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "valet";

                    // Create connection
                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    // Check connection
                    if (!$conn) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    }
                    $age = array();

                     $sql = "SELECT  company_name ,acess_code ,register_on  FROM `tbl_companies` where id=".$_REQUEST['id'] ." ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                       // echo "User name=" . $row["name"]. "<br>";



if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                             $age[] = $row;          

?>


                <br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="company_name" value="<?php  echo $row["company_name"] ?>" name="company_name" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Company Name*">
                <br>
                <br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="acess_code" value="<?php echo $row["acess_code"] ?>" name="acess_code" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Acess Code*">
                <br><br><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="register_on" value="<?php echo $row["register_on"] ?>" name="register_on" style="width: 460px;height: 50px;overflow: hidden;" placeholder="Register On*">
                <br><br><br><br>

                <button name="editcompany"  id="editcompany" type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 45px;" >
                <img src="images/save.png" alt="">

                </button>
                <button type="submit" style="border:0;width:100px;margin-left: 75px;">
                <img src="images/cancel.png" alt="">
                </button>




                <?php
}
                   }


mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>          
                </form> 

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code... here i created example for you

```
   <script>
   function getComboB(sel) { 
   var roomtype=document.getElementById("roomtype");
   var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
   checkin.action = "checkin.php?item_combo="+value+"&roomtype="+value+"";
   checkin.submit();

   }
   </script>


<form>
<select name="roomtype" id="roomtype" style="width:150px;"  onchange="getComboB(this)">
<option><--Select--> </option>
<?php 


$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM roomtype order by id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

$val2=$row['id'];

?>
<option  value="<?=$val2;?>"  <? if ($_GET['roomtype']  == $val2) { echo "selected='selected'"; }?> > <?=$row['roomtype'];?> </option>


<?php }?>
</form>
```

`